# regex to match a string without whitespaces between two #

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex, which returns a string between two hashtags,
but only if between the two # there is no whitespace.

My current regex: `\#(.*?)\#`

Testcase 1:

```
'#thisshouldbeparsed# #2 test'
=> thisshouldbeparsed (this is currently correct)
```

Testcase 2:

```
'test #2 #thisshouldbeparsed#'

=>2 (this is not correct)
```

I need a regex which is returning also `"thisshouldbeparsed"`.

Comment: Use `#([^#\s]*)#`

Comment: FYI, you don't need to escape `#`.

Comment: You may want to use `+` rather than `*`, so you won't match `##`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
#([^#\s]*)#
```

To avoide empty matches, replace `*` with `+`:

```
#([^#\s]+)#
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FJVUiR/1).

**Details**

- `#` - a `#` char
- `([^#\s]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `#` and whitespace
- `#` - a `#` char.